# Google Play загрузка APK бета-тестирования после релиза

Tags: android, google-play

Имею приложение на Google Play с пользователями.
Добавил некий функционал в это приложение и хочу его протестировать.
Если я загружу новый APK файл в раздел бета-тестированик то что произойдет?
Пользователи ничего не заметят(На текущем релизе это ни как не отразится), а я просто получу отдельно ссылку на бета релиз или у всех обновится до новой "тестовой версии"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы получите ссылку для регистрации как бета-тестер и сможете раздать ее всем желающим. Все зарегистрированные бета-тестеры получат в качестве обновления новое приложение (автоматически, как любое другое обновление приложения). Все остальные его не увидят, пока вы в консоли не измените его статус на релизное.

Comment: tse, подскажите. Тестер купил приложение деньги снялись и вернулись на карту. Но как под этим же тестером повторно преобрести app? Если что-то пофиксил например...Как удалить эту покупку? Не вкурсе? Спасибо.

Comment: С тестированием покупок отдельная история, я не пробовал. Задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Как оперативно) Спасибо)